# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.n_user" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql

Возникает вышеназванная проблема.

Запрос `select 1 from public.n_user`.

Структура БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите как в жпа ставится схема у энтити, либо добавьте в дата сурс url  + /public

Comment: Вы выполняете запрос вручную или программно?

Comment: Использовал аннотацию `@Table(name = "n_user" schema="public")`?
Если нет - укажи что рабочая схема - public
и в hql можно будет использовать `select 1 from User` (а лучше - `from User` и `query.uniqueResult()`)

Answer (score 0):

В pg названия идут без подчёркивания с маленькой буквы. Иначе их надо взять в кавычки. Был случай когда я написал название таблицы с большой и только с кавычками к ней можно было делать запросы